# When can we expect live deployment of the Plutus Playground

Tags: plutus-playground

I am working with a low end device, and the live deployment of the playground is what I'm counting on. When can I expect it and is there any community deployed server that is active now?

Answer (score 1):

You may already be aware , but the **live deployment is back online**, as posted on Discord by Matthew Capps.

For future reference, this was in the `ppp-announcements` channel on the `IOG Discord server`. A lot of the most current info is shared out there by IO(HK).

Good luck and wish you the best in this class!

Comment: Can you share a link to the deployment? I was not able to find it on Discord.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's online and available [here](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/). Not sure what version it is though.